# Find all integers less than $m$ that are relatively prime to it

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Find all integers $n$ between $0\le n < m$ that are relatively prime to $m$, for $m =
4,5,9, 26$. We denote the number of integers $n$ which fulfill the condition by $\phi (m)$,
e.g. $\phi (3) = 2$. This function is called "Euler's phi function". What is $\phi (m)$ for $m =4,5,9,26$?

Comment: The instructions seem clear enough to be carried out. First problem, $m=4$. We are to look at $0,1,2,3$, identify which ones are relatively prime to $4$, and count them. That count will be $\varphi(4)$. Then move on to $m=5$.

Answer (score 1):

$m$ and $n$ relatively prime is equivalent to $gcd(m,n)=1$.  Consider the prime factorizations:
$4=2^2$, $5=5^1$, $9=3^2$ and $26=2^*13$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing a solution i'll suggest you to consider looking and proving the [properties of the totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). (And so you'll be able to finish a wider class of excercise of this kind)

You are interested in **multiplicativity** and **behaviour of the function with power of a prime**.